# Handle time of received interrupt in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, interrupt

I have an external controller with only one button connected to PC with RS232.
Operating in Windows, I want to know the time of hardware interrupt being received.
Time of control being received by user application process is incorrect here.

I want to know the way of redefining the primary ISR (like asm "int 14h") in Windows?
Or maybe there is also a way how to this already catched time in user application (so no redefinition is required)?

Comment: Int14 is the old BIOS access method for DOS, it didn't use an ISR.  Windows does, it is buried in the device driver.  You'll have to make your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int 14H is right for actually handling the UART on COM1 or COM2: [**see here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call). But setting up an ISR is a different matter and for that I would look around for a BIOS listing. It might be hard to find, but I don't believe there's any way around it. Try googling "pc BIOS listing"; you might get lucky.

There is a way to chain ISRs together so that you don't put too much hurt on the Windows driver.

Oh, here you go. Google "pc interrupt service routine" to find a whole bunch of references.

And, hey! Good luck!